# Eclipse Scout Http Deploy on Tomcat fails

Tags: java, eclipse-scout

I tried to deploy my eclipse scout application (framework) on tomcat. I configured the application to http correctly. 
The server and consequently the UI can't start.

Here's the stacktrace of the exception:

```
[33msyscodeapp_1  |[0m Exception in thread "Thread-6" 19-Nov-2016 04:50:49.525 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/org.eclipse.scout.sysmanagement.org.eclipse.scout.sysmanagement.ui.html] startup failed due to previous errors
[33msyscodeapp_1  |[0m java.lang.NullPointerException
[33msyscodeapp_1  |[0m        at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.internal.PlatformImplementor.fireStateEvent(PlatformImplementor.java:308)
[33msyscodeapp_1  |[0m        at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.internal.PlatformImplementor.changeState(PlatformImplementor.java:284)
[33msyscodeapp_1  |[0m        at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.internal.PlatformImplementor.start(PlatformImplementor.java:141)
[33msyscodeapp_1  |[0m        at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.internal.PlatformStarter.run(PlatformStarter.java:32)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some information which Scout version you are using?
Maven artifact version for example

Comment: Hi Patrick I've now posted the solution to my problem. ¨

Comment: I've seen that you are part of BSI and therefore I want to inform you that you should adapt your eclipse scout beginners guide at point: "2.4.3. Update the Scout Application to work with HTTP". You should mention that one has to adapt the property: "scout.server.url" from 
https: //localhost:8443/...
to http: //localhost:8080/...
This wasn't the problem for me, because I noticed it and mapped consequently the server still correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent input @PrestigeDev.
I committed an update to the documentation which will show up on the next rebuild of the website.
Feel free to open issues or send us a Pull Request for the documentation at https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs

Comment: The change you suggested should now be visible in the updated documentation. Thank you for helping to make Scout better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Since I was running my tomcat on docker I used the latest available image of tomcat:8.0. After long research I noticed that the JVM version of my tomcat was Java 1.7, but I compiled my project on Java 1.8. That was the reason for the strange errors.

Now deployment works completely fine. I hope that this post helps others not to lose much time anymore for this kind of error.